# MySql: Get name of a product from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `movimiento` which stores the amount of pieces sold by `productit`

```
idProducto  Cantidad
   8878       2
   8897       3
   8878       5
   8878       2
   8897       3
   8878       5
   8878       2
   8897       3
   8878       5
```

and another table called producto in where I store the product detail

```
idProducto      Nombre
   8878       Tasa Verde
   8897       Tasa Roja
```

I'm trying to make a query to get the sum of sales by product id, which I have done this :

```
SELECT idProducto,
   SUM(cantidad) AS c
FROM movimiento
GROUP BY idProducto
```

and it's working fine, but I'm trying to put in the query result the name of the product based on the name in table `producto`

The query below is not working :

```
    select producto.descripcion
from 
(
SELECT movimiento.idProducto,
       SUM(cantidad) AS c
FROM movimiento, producto
GROUP BY movimiento.idProducto
) as rSum
GROUP BY producto.descripcion
```

an have tried this too, but nothing

```
select descripcion from producto where idProducto in (
   select idProducto, SUM(cantidad) as c
from movimiento
group by idProducto
   )
```

Comment: you could post the expected output and current output that will make more clarity about what you are trying

Comment: your sub query must return one column so as to work in where clause. and where is your producto.descripcion I can see Nombre column only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) to link the id to the description of the product...

```
SELECT p.descripcion, SUM(m.cantidad) AS c
    FROM movimiento m
    JOIN producto p ON m.idProducto = p.idProducto
    GROUP BY p.descripcion
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query is not correct, as you are trying to get `producto.descripcion` from inline view query. But that column doesn't exist in your inline view.

```
select producto.descripcion
from 
/* This represents as inline view */
(
SELECT movimiento.idProducto,
       SUM(cantidad) AS c
FROM movimiento, producto
GROUP BY movimiento.idProducto
) as rSum
/* This represents as inline view */
GROUP BY producto.descripcion
```

I think, what you are looking for is to `JOIN` the tables and then use `GROUP BY` on `description` column, which @Nigel has already shared sample query.